# Have i misused/overused the async/await pattern?

Tags: asynchronous

I admit that i don't have a quite deep understanding of the async/await pattern. I just read some articles and got the impression that this pattern is good so i used it everywhere. My service layer is stuffed with code like this:

```
public async Task DoSomeWork()
{
// some database operations...
await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();   
}
```

And in my async controller action methods:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SomeAction()
{
await service.DoSomeWork();
return View();
}
```

In most of my projects, the iis server and database server are in the same intranet, even on the same physical server. So i don't think i gain any benefit from using async, but rather suffered from the drawbacks of it, one of which is the page doesn't show any exception during development stage and i have experienced thousand times while debugging that stepping into an await line of code simply got no response, no exception, no break.

So, do i misuse or overuse the async/await pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async is good for two things: on UI applications, async provides responsiveness; on server applications, async provides scalability.

In the case of an ASP.NET server, the question of whether to use async generally comes down to how scalable your *backend* is. This is because most of the time, it's the database server that is the bottleneck. If your backend is scalable (e.g., NoSQL), then using async on the web server generally makes sense. But if you have a single instance of SQL server as your bakend, then an async web server usually does not make sense.